# "I main this champion" < what does this mean for real?

Tags: league-of-legends

I always knew that the "main" term is used to specify your lane and/or champion specialty

AFAIK, saying that your x champion is your main, means that you do have a deep knowledge and practise (or practice?) about the plays to make, the items, the matchups, mechanics, not to mention that is also the champion that suits you better to handle almost every situation.

Now what if another person says "I main this champion in top, and I main this other in mid"? Is that ok to say, that the player "mains" more than one champion?

Comment: I think you answered your own question ... if someone says they main a champion top, it means they know the champion in a top lane matchup, but not necessarily in other lanes. What do you mean by "is that ok?"?

Comment: Not sure how to ask it. I remember people saying "you only main one champion in one lane, a player doesn't main another but that one", but sometimes I see people saying "I main ryze mid, irelia top, nocturne jungle, lucian adc, and lulu support"... Which makes me think uncertainly about the concept of "main champion".

Comment: Is this still unclear?

Comment: @Fabián Well it's not unclear but seriously... There's not much to interpret into it. You basically answer the question yourself with your last sentence.

Comment: Saying "I main a so and so" means that you have a relatively good understanding of that champion's mechanics and playstyle. For example,  I "main" nidalee. This means that I have a good understanding of her mechanics and playstyle. She is NOT, however, the only champion I can play. I have a fairly deep pool, but I feel the most confident playing her in most matchups. In short, don't worry about having a "main". Develop confidence with multiple champions in multiple situations and games will be won :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A main champion is basically just your best/strongest champion. Really there's not much to interpret into it, it's as simple as that.

But yeah often people have different main champs for different situations and/or lanes.

When someone says: "I main Vladimir top, Fizz Mid and Leona as a counter to Sona" that basically just means "My best champion for top is Vladimir, for mid it's Fizz and when facing a Sona it's Leona"

Answer (score 0):

It's short for saying "I use this as my main champion for this particular lane".
When a champion is your "main", it means you use it the most and are the most comfortable playing with.

Pretty much what you said already...